# What is maximum size of data that an object can hold on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, object

What is maximum size of data that an object can hold on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of memory the iPhone currently can allocate to an object is the amount of memory currently available.

Conceptually, there is no **limit**. The iPhone itself does have physical limits, though.

**You must test your apps on the iPhone heavily before releasing an app that will get arbitrary length data.**

**You should make sure that the data length is within reasonable bounds. 
The last thing you want is `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` being called and your app exiting.**

Comment: means a NSString object can hold some MB or GB of data ?

Comment: In theory, yes. I would strongly discourage doing so though.

Comment: Actually, i am reading data from file and assign to an object of NSStrig or Dictionary or array . and may be data in bulk, Is this create any problem ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no size limit.

(Except limited by the RAM and pointer bit-size.)